# Show Toast message at 10 minute interval

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a `Toast` message to the user at a 10 minute interval. I'm doing this:

```
triggerAtTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2011-07-12 14:00:00").getTime();
```

... and now I want to display a `Toast` message when the system time has reached the given time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use service for this, In service you can get the time of system and check it for giving time. After for every 10 minutes just display Toast.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).